# Git automatically marks my file as "assumed-unchanged"

Tags: git

My git is broken for a month and I am not able to fix it yet. Following are the details of the issue:

1. git status (no changes found)
2. Modify a file.
3. git status (1 file modified)
4. I commit and push the change to origin
5. Run git status (no changes found). Till this, it is all ok.
6. If I modify same file again, then git status does not show that file is modified.

I found following:

git automatically marks the committed file as assume-unchanged. I have to mark the no-assume-unchanged for git status to recognize the change.

I am doing this for almost 2 weeks but could not figure out the reason behind it.

I am using git-bash (MINGW32) and found similar issue with git-gui as well. I tried another git client but found similar issue. Therefore, I think, somehow my git configuration has changed. Not sure which config though.

Any inputs will be great.

Thank you

Comment: Can you check your [`core.ignoreStat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreStat) config entry?

Comment: The "assume unchanged" bit is set and cleared by Git internally if you use the sparse checkout feature. Are you doing so? (If so, that's probably the issue.) If not, try using `git ls-files` to see if you can detect what other (presumably non-Git) software is literally running `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. See my Python [`git-flagged`](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged) program for a way to do this programmatically.

Comment: Hi @RomainValeri   Thank you for your comment. It is set to true.  

    $ git config --get core.ignorestat
    true

Thank you

Comment: Hi @torek Thank you for your comment. I am not using _spare_ checkout function. I haven't come across it. To try the script [git-flagged](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged), first I replicated issue as I described in my initial post (my committed file is set to "assume-unchanged" (flag set to "h"). `git ls-files -v | grep ^h` lists my file). Then I ran script [git-flagged](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged) with -l flag but it did not produce any results. Thank you

Comment: Ah, @RomainValeri's earlier question (and your answer) provides the real answer here: with `core.ignoreStat` set to `true`, Git itself will set the assume-unchanged bit, to make various commands run faster. You then have to clear the bit manually, or use `git update-index` directly. It seems odd that my script failed on your system (Windows?) but I have not tested it there, only on Unix-like systems (including macOS).

Comment: @RomainValeri, Thank you. `git config --global core.ignoreStat false` worked. This issue is fixed.

Comment: @Torek, Thank you for assisting with this issue. I looked a bit further into the script [git-flagged](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged). Issue is related to byte string. If I replace `line[0] == b'h'` as `line[0] == b'h'[0]`, then that condition passes through. Just for info, reason for change I made is, line[0] is byte value of 'h' which is 104 whereas b'h' is list of byte value which is [104]. Thank you

Comment: Ah, it's a py2k vs py3k ism that slipped through cracks. Will fix.